# Clone form elements, then wrap them in a div, then append?

Tags: jquery, clone

I'm getting all the inputs from a form and cloning them into another form.  This is working great (with the fix of jquery.fix.clone.js).  I'm now simply trying to wrap the elements into a div, which isnt working because jquery always adds the other half of the tag, like `<div></div>`

```
addbutt = $("form.prodform button.add");
    addbutt.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        theform = $(this).closest('form');
        $(theform).each(function(){
            //lets validate,then we add
            $('form#Receiver').append('<div class="appended">');
            $('form#Receiver').append($(this).find('div.name') .clone());
            $('form#Receiver').append($(this).find(':input').not(':button') .clone());
            $('form#Receiver').append('<button>delete</button>');           
            $('form#Receiver').append('</div>');
        });
    })
```

I tried using html() to get the found inputs, but this just gets the input, not the value.
Tried like this:

```
inputs = $(this).find(':input').not(':button');
            $.each(inputs, function(i, val){
                inouts = inouts + $(val).prop('outerHTML');
            });
```

Also tried many variations on `$('form#Receiver').append($(this).find('.name') .clone().html())`

So, I know what I need to do is find my inputs and clone them...into my wrapper div.  How can I store the cloned elements, to put them in a div, like:

```
$('form#Receiver').append('<div class="appended">' + namediv + inputs + '</div>');
```

Here is the working result, thanks @Derek Story

```
addbutt = $("form.prodform button.add");
addbutt.click(function(e){
    var inputs = [];
    var divs = [];
    var theform = $(this).closest('form');
    e.preventDefault();     
    theform.find(':input').not(':button').each(function() {//using :intput cuz it might be selects, etc.
      inputs.push($(this).clone());
    });
    theform.find('div.name').each(function() {
      divs.push($(this).clone());
    });

    var container = $('<div class="appended" />').append(divs, inputs);
    $('form#Receiver').append(container);
})
```

And let me add, in order for clone() to work on selects and textareas, you need this https://github.com/spencertipping/jquery.fix.clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store cloned elements you can push them into an array like:

```
var inputs = [];
$('input').each(function() {
  inputs.push($(this).clone());
});
```

To wrap them in a new element, you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
// create the wrapper and append the cloned elements
var container = $('<div class="appended" />').append(namediv, inputs); 
// append the wrapper
$('form#Receiver').append(container);
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXdxjV)

Comment: This looks pretty good, but I'm not sure where to insert the input.pushing part.  Within `$(theform).each(function(){` ?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you need to wrap your stuff in that `each()` statement. The variable is only grabbing one with `.closest()`, so you aren't really looping through anything. If you are checking to see if it exist, then use a `.length` check in an if statement.

Comment: There are many forms on the page, each with an 'add' button.  I need to grab all the inputs from only the selected form.  (this is my thought process, I'm not saying it's correct) .  It looks like yours is going to grab every input on the page.

Comment: `theForm` only returns a single form though. So there is no need to loop through `theForm`. My example is just an example. You can use the same method to grab the specific inputs you need. Still storing them in an array. I'm also not sure why you are adding colons in `(":input")` and (":button")

Comment: And to only get the inputs for that form, you can just do `theForm.find('input')`

Comment: Looping theForm:  ahh, ok, I thought i was looping thru elements *in* theForm, not all theForm's that it found.  `:input` because it needs to get selects, too (and maybe in the future checks and radios)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
    $('form#Receiver').append($('<div class="appended">')
       .append($(this).find('div.name') .clone())
       .append($(this).find(':input').not(':button') .clone())
       .append('<button>delete</button>')
    );
```